# Netty: Using `IdleStateHandler` to detect disconnection

Tags: java, android, netty

I read the documentation of [`IdleStateHandler`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html)and from my Server I implemented it same as from the documentation, 
but I don't understand on how can I exactly tell if the Client become disconnected for example the Client loses the Wifi Connectivity.

from my understanding, inside my Handler, the method `channelInactive()` was trigger when the client become disconnected, 
then using `IdleStateHandler`, the `IdleState.READER_IDLE` will be triggered when no read was performed for the specified period of time, 
then after 3 seconds of no read from the client I closed the channel and was expecting that the `channelInactive` will be trigger but it's not, why?.

**Initializer**

```
public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    String TAG = "LOG: ";
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(TAG + "Starting ServerInitializer class...");
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(6, 3, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerHandler());
    }
}
```

**Handler**

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private String TAG = "LOG: ";

    public ServerHandler(){}

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        Log.w(TAG,"New Client become connected, Sending a message to the Client. Client Socket is: " + ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString());

        List<String> msg = new ArrayList<>();
        msg.add(0,"sample message 1");
        msg.add(1,"sample message 2");
        sendMessage(ctx, msg);
    }

    public void sendMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, List message){
        ctx.write(message);
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        Log.w(TAG,"A Client become disconnected. Client Socket is: " + ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString() + " id: " + (String.valueOf(ctx.channel().hashCode())));
         //COnnection id dead, do something here...
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object object) { // (2)
        Log.w(TAG, "CLIENT: "+ ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString() + " SAYS: " + object);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) { // (4)
        // Close the connection for that client  when an exception is raised.
        Log.e(TAG,"Something's wrong, CLIENT: "+ ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString() + " CAUSE: " + cause.toString());
        ctx.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        Log.w(TAG,"LOLO");
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
            IdleStateEvent e = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
            if (e.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {

                ctx.close(); //Closed the Channel so that the `channelInactive` will be trigger

            } else if (e.state() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {

                ctx.writeAndFlush("ping\n"); //Send ping to client

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Anyone can help me out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IdleStateHandler` should always be the first handler in your pipeline.

Comment: I have the same problem, need to set a 'keep-alive' time for connections. But in my case, each connection can have a different keep-alive time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ReadTimeoutHandler instead of IdleStateHandler and override the exceptionCaught method.